# Displaying categories and subcategories without link

Tags: categories, links, woocommerce-offtopic

I want the categories and subcategories to be displayed on my single product pages, but I dont want them linking. I've found some really nice code here [WooCommerce - how to display product category above product?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89819/woocommerce-how-to-display-product-category-above-product)

That works great but the subcategories are missing... I am not strong in coding so I cant do it myself, someone can modify the code so all categories of a product are showing?

The code I found here was posted by helgatheviking and goes like this:

```
       function wpa89819_wc_single_product(){

       $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

        if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

       $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

    <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>
```

Thanks in advance!
Kelly

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a PHP question and it is related to WooCommerce. Either of which conditions makes it dangerously close to off-topic. However, I am going to give the benefit of the doubt and assume that the problem is due to a misunderstanding of the WordPress function `wp_get_post_terms()`. ;)

[`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) returns all of the terms as an array of term object. By using `array_shift()` the way you are you are truncating that list down to one. Remove `array_shift()` and create a loop.

```
$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
// var_dump($product_cats); // debug
if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){
  while (!empty($product_cats)) {
    $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>
    <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2><?php
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much, I am very new to this to sorry about the misunderstanding... Ok, I'll try and do what you suggest, alldough I dont really understand... I'll try and look further so I can understand the answer you gave.